# Alternative of Hierachical Select

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I see this module is currently old and not maintained by the developers. Is there any alternative module for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Simple Hierarchical Select](https://drupal.org/project/shs).

> Simple hierarchical select defines a new form widget for taxonomy
>   fields to select a term by "browsing" through the vocabularies
>   hierarchy. The widget is available in node forms and as Views exposed
>   filter.